# Is there a way i can send an array of objects in react native in which the objects contains text and the corresponding onPRess action for the texts?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to be able to create a child component which acts like a section of links with text and corresponding navigate actions. My main Screen has the following:

```
const linkList = [{
title: "Some information",
onPress: () => {
  this.navigation.navigate("WebViewScreen", {
    title: "Some title",
    uri: "https://SomeLink.com"
  });
}},{
title: "Some information2",
onPress: () => {
  this.navigation.navigate("WebViewScreen", {
    title: "Some title2",
    uri: "https://SomeLink2.com"
  });
} }];
```

Inside the render section i have

```
<GuideLinkSection links={linkList} />
```

My constructor looks like this:

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.navigation = navigation;
  }
```

In my child component i have :

```
    renderGuideListSection = () => {
    const { links, navigat } = this.props;
    return links.map(link => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.view} onPress={link.onPress}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={LinkImage} />
          <Text style={styles.titleText}>{link.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
};



   render() {
    return this.renderGuideListSection();
  }
```

This gives me an error : "Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined. Is there a way i can achieve this without using multiple props?

Comment: Why not use a single function that deals with navigation and pass arguments to it from the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let linkList = [
{
  title: 'Some information',
  navigateTo: 'WebViewScreen',
  label: 'Some title',
  uri: 'https://SomeLink.com'
},
{
  title: 'Some information2',
  navigateTo: 'WebViewScreen2',
  label: 'Some title2',
  uri: 'https://SomeLink2.com'
}
];
```

You can store the array as above.

Below is your method that will be called on `onPress`.

```
redirectTo = ({navigateTo, label, uri}) => {
   let {navigation} = this.props;
   navigation.navigate(navigateTo, {
     title,
     uri
   })
}
```

```
renderGuideListSection = () => {
const { links } = this.props;
return links.map(link => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.view} onPress={() => this.RedirectTo(link)}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={LinkImage} />
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>{link.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});
```